# Get transactions from Google Pay API

Tags: android, google-api, transactions, google-pay

For my app I want to get all recent and upcomming transactions a user has. I looked at the Google Pay API and form my perspective, it just provides the functionality of make payments through your own app.

Just like I would fetch transaction data for example from Paypal, I want to do this with Google Pay. Is there anything like that provided by Google? Or maybe a way to get the information from the Google Pay app itself on the device?

Unfortunately I did not find anything helpful in my reseach.

Comment: Unfortunately, no such API exists at the moment.

Comment: @Soc do you know wether this is planned or available now?

Comment: No current plans. This is more of a feature request at this stage.

Comment: @CrystalCase did you get something on that?

Comment: @halcyoona unfortunately not. But I stopped researching shortly after. There might be something new in the mean time